# how to wait till uiimageview resize in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Normally when we add a big image to UIImageView (This image view is a subview) , it takes whole window size because UIImageView needs some time to resize the image view. I want to get the minimum resize time (afterDelay time).

```
    self.capturedImgV.image =image;
    [self performSelector:@selector(resizeImageView) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSelector:@selector(resizeImageView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
                self.capturedImgV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            });
```

We can resize the UIImageView asynchronous request. Then it will resize without delay.

Comment: Interesting in your original code you set the delay as 1 second. That is probably why you saw a delay., probably around a second. This new code is using 0 for the delay. Why not use 0  in the original code. It still gets scheduled on the run loop so should give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The following article discusses different ways to scale images and presents timings for scaling images of different types.

http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

The important information is the relative timings between approaches. UIKit seems to come out well, so it may be you are better not to worry and accept the speed as it is given you can probably do very little about it other than rendering smaller versions yourself in the background and then setting the view to your reduced version in one go.

A thought was you could have provided a subclass of `UIImageView` and implemented its `drawRect:` method to do timings, but it looks like because `UIImageView` is optimized to draw directly to the screen that this is not called when the image is drawn.

> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display.
>   UIImageView does not call the drawRect: method of its subclasses. If
>   your subclass needs to include custom drawing code, you should
>   subclass the UIView class instead.